# Trouble running tensorflow serving on different macs: CHECK failed: file != nullptr

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm struggling to run the same tensorflow serving docker image on two different mac computers.
Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.6.0
RUN mkdir /models
WORKDIR /models
COPY ./ /models
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8080 --model_name=MyModel --model_base_path=/models/
```

When I build and run this on Mac 1, it works fine.
However, on Mac 2, the following error occurs:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc:2345] CHECK failed: file != nullptr:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: file != nullptr:
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
Aborted
```

Does anyone know why is happening, and how to prevent it? Thanks!

Mac 1 specs:

```
MacOS Monterey Version 12.5
Processor: Quad-Core Intel Core i7
```

Mac2 specs:

```
  MacOS Monterey Version 12.0.1 (21A559)
  Chip:    Apple M1 Pro
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this error. Yet if it works with i7 and not M1, it might be because your TensorFlow serving image does not work with arm64 arch. You may need a custom build

I have found one here : [build for apple's M1](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1816)

but I am having difficulties myself to run it.

Edit: actually it runs now